# Проблема 0xc0000005 при запуске приложений

Tags: windows

Возникает проблема при запуске некоторых (не всех) приложений. Вместо запуска появляется окно с надписью: "Ошибка при запуске приложения (0xc0000005)". Смотрел видеография по лечению, ничего не выходит. В частности, пробовал:

- переустановить косячное приложение
- провериться на вирусы
- удалить обновления Винды
- обновить драйвера

Comment: Вы уже задавали подобный вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900945/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-0xc0000005-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-unreal-engine - возможно, у Вас просто "разломана windows" - то есть, поврежденны системные файлы. Тут сложно что то рекомендовать, самое простое - переустановить винду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная ошибка иногда возникает при запуске 32-битных приложений на компьютере, где одновременно установлены определенные версии Kaspersky Antivirus и CryptoPro (точные версии не вспомню, но ошибка возникает именно при их сочетании. CryptoPro уже исправились в более новых версиях)

Исправляется правкой реестра. Ключ

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\CProPatches\Force
```

надо установить в "1"